# Cannot load scikit-learn

Tags: python, import, installation, scikit-learn

When I try to import sklearn, I get the following error message:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

(In English: The specified module was not found)

I'm working on Windows 10, 64-Bit. I'm using Python 3.6.1. (and no other version), Anaconda and PyCharm. I installed scikit-learn using

> conda install scikit-learn

and I can find it in

> conda list

as well as in File | Settings | Project Interpreter with version 0.19.1. I also have numpy 1.13.3 and scipy 1.0.0.

I know this error message has been discussed multiple, but none of these discussions could help me ... 
I tried uninstalling and re-installing numpy, scipy and scikit-learn. I also tried installing scikit-learn using pip.
If I randomly try to load other packages, that are in my conda list, they all work perfectly fine, but not scikit-learn.

I don't even know where my error is. Can anyone give me a hint in the right direction, or a suggestion what I could try?

Thanks!

Comment: Did u try gohlke [libs](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn)

Comment: Try conda install sklearn

Comment: Did u have visual c++ >14

Comment: @Sam this yields PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels

Comment: @SmartManoj I neither tried the libs nor have I visual c++ installed. Are these necessary for sklearn to work, or are these suggestions of you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to import sklearn directly from a Python interpreter ?

Also, try to check in your Project Settings that sklearn is recognized as a package of the Python interpreter associated (Settings --> Project --> Project Interpreter)

Comment: Yes, sklearn is recognized as a package, I find it in my interpreter. I also import sklearn directly from an interpreter. Additionally, when I start writing "import sk" in the interpreter, PyCharm suggests sklearn. But still, when I run the script, I get the error message ...

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. The version of Sklearn was 0.14.1 and when I did a py -3.6 -m pip install --upgrade scipy I got the message that the version I have is current.  But sklearn was not recognized from within Jupyter or from the Idle environment.  So I went to the site https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scikit-learn, downloaded the correct .whl file, and installed it.  Now I can import it.
By the way, to use scikit-learn, you will need both numpy and mkl.